# Mounting Ceph on /etc/fstab throws me in emergency mode on machine reboot

Tags: filesystems, persistent, reboot, ceph

Prerequisites :

Jewel 10.2.3
OS : Centos 7.2

1 admin machine named : ceph-admin
1 monitor machine : ceph-mon1 (ip : 192.168.0.171)
1 metadataserver : ceph-mds1
3 OSD : ceph-osd1 ceph-osd2 ceph-osd3

The cluster is up an running nicely.

i setup a new machine called ceph-client.

If i mount manually the filesystem on it everything works just fine.

I edit the fstab and add the line :

```
192.168.0.171:6789:/ /mnt ceph name=admin,secretfile=/etc/ceph/admin.secret,noatime 0 2
```

If i want to mount the fs :

```
mount /mnt
```

Will mount the fs.

Problem comes when i reboot that machine i expect after reboot if i run a df to see the filesystem mounted, but it doesn`t works as i expect, instead throws me into emergency mode and i can only give root passwd for maintenance.

Any ideeas what`s happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For all poor bastards that are cracking their skulls trying to setup the automount according to ceph main page i recommend following the tutorial from :

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en/red-hat-ceph-storage/2/paged/ceph-file-system-guide-technology-preview/chapter-4-mounting-and-unmounting-ceph-file-systems#mounting-cephfs-fstab

The line that i added in fstab looks like this :

```
192.168.0.171:6789:/ /mnt ceph name=admin,secretfile=/etc/ceph/admin.secret,_netdev,noatime     0 0
```

I was missing the _netdev and also the rank 0 0

"In all cases, use the _netdev option. This option ensures that the file system is mounted after the networking subsystem to prevent networking issues." -  quote from redhat`s page.

Hope it will help you out guys. It creeped me 2 hours.